# mongoose update query going beyong min value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have products and transaction model. If a user place a transaction its supposed to subtract the quantity of his order into the products. However, if the transaction quantity is higher than the set minimum of the product, it still proceeds. Making the product have a negative quantity number.

```
router.route("/add").post(async (req, res) => {
  const { f_name, l_name, order } = req.body;

  try {
    const newTransaction = new Transaction({
      f_name,
      l_name,
      order,
    });

    for (const product of order) {
      let newProduct = await Products.findOneAndUpdate(
        { product: product.product },
        { $inc: { stocks: -product.quantity } }
      );

      await newProduct.save();
    }

    await newTransaction.save();
    res.status(200).json(newTransaction);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error.message);
  }
});
```

Product model. the minimum should be 0.

```
const userInventoryModel = new Schema({
  product: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  stocks: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    min: 0,
  },
  basePrice: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    min: [0, "Value must be greater than 0."],
  },
  sellPrice: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    min: [0, "Value must be greater than 0"],
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation is a middleware and Mongoose runs validation before saving the model into a database, not before `findAndUpdate` so just try

```
for (const product of order) {
      let newProduct = await Products.findOne({ product: product.product });
        //implement the business logic
        newProduct.stocks = newProduct.stocks - product.quantity// it's an exmaple
         await newProduct.save();
}
```

if you want get the data after updating use new : ture

```
    for (const product of order) {
      let newProduct = await Products.findOneAndUpdate(
        { product: product.product },
        { $inc: { stocks: -product.quantity } },
        {new : true}
      );

      await newProduct.save();
    }
```

in this method you can see the error